# English to Pig Latin in C++ using specific functions

Tags: c++, string, function, data-structures

Ok, so I'm working on a project that requires us to translate English to Pig Latin. I was trying to kind of copy and tweak some code I found online that did the opposite because the functions kind of looked similar. In my class, we are given certain functions that have to be implemented in our code.

This has to be present in my source code:

```
struct Word
{
    string english;
    string pigLatin;
};
```

Function 1: `Word * splitSentence(const string words, int &size);` ~ Takes the English sentence as 1 string

Function 2: `void convertToPigLatin(Word [] wordArr, int size);` ~ Converts English to Pig Latin

Function 3: `void convertToPigLatin(Word [] wordArr, int size);` ~ Display

Here is the code that I have. 
Edit: The problem I'm having is that I don't have `wordArr` declared anywhere in my code so it can't compile. I also noticed a few minor errors and changed my code a little. You'll have to excuse me I'm very tired right now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

struct Word
{
    string english;
    string pigLatin;
};

Word * splitSentence(wordArr&; int &);
void convertToPigLatin (Word[], int);
void displayPigLatin (Word[], int);

int main()
{
    string userInput;
    int size;

    cout <<"This is an English to Pig Latin translator.\n";
    cout <<"Enter a sentance that you want to translate.\n";
    getline(cin, userInput);

    Word *wordArr = convertToPigLatin(userInput, size); 
    displayPigLatin(wordArr, size);

return 0;
}

Word * splitSentence(const Word [] wordArr, int &size)
{

    int num = 0;
    int phraseLength = userInput.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (isspace(userInput[i]))
        {
            if (isspace(userInput[ i - 1]))
            {
                num--;
            }
            num++;
        }
    }

    if (ispunct(userInput[i]))
    {
        if (i != (phraseLength - 1))
        {
            userInput.erase(1--, 1)
        }
    }
}

void convertToPigLatin(Word wordArr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int stringLength;

        if (i == (size - 1))
            {
                stringLength = wordArr[i].userInput.length();
            }

        else
            {
                stringLength = wordArr[i].userInput.length() - 1;
            }

        string vowel, way;
        vowel = wordArr[i].userInput.at(stringLength - stringLength);
        way = wordArr[i].userInput.at(stringLength - 3);
        bool markV = ((vowel == 'A') || (vowel == 'a') (vowel == 'E') || (vowel == 'e')
        (vowel == 'I') || (vowel == 'i') (vowel == 'O') || (vowel == 'o') 
        (vowel == 'U') || (vowel == 'u'));

        wordArr[i].userInput.erase(stringLength - 3, 3);

        if (!(markV && (way == 'w')))
        {
            wordArr[i].english = way + wordArr[i].userInput;
        }
    }

    displayPigLatin(wordArr, stringLength);
}

void displayPigLatin(const Word wordArr[], int size);
{
    cout << "\nHere is your phrase in PigLatin: ";
    for (int i = 0 i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << wordArr[i].userInput << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: so is the code working? if not what about it is not working?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Its full of errors to be honest. Like some of my declarations are messed up. No matter what I do I can't declare wordArr.

Comment: Must the functions be the same as well (**I see three**) or is it allowed to do all of it in one?

Comment: Yeah the function should be the same I just tried to change them to get it to even work for me

Comment: `Word * splitSentence(wordArr&**;** int &);`->`Word * splitSentence(wordArr&**,** int &);` What's a `wordArr` anyway?

Comment: @RoyalWeirdo Also, what is **wordArr&** in the declaration `Word * splitSentence(wordArr&, int &);`?

Comment: wordArr is just in the function declarations given to me and I have to include it. I might've tried to change it before I posted the code. I'm kinda tired right now its really late.

Comment: Programming is pretty finicky work. Do it slowly. Do it carefully.  Write a few lines. Compile them test them Don't write any more until they work perfectly. If you just sit down and spit letters out like it's a sociology paper you're going to BS your way through, you are *hosed*.  Write a few lines. Make sure they are right. Then write a few more lines. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: If you want help with errors, it would be helpful if you told us what the errors are. Can you copy and paste the compilation errors into your question, so we can see them? And if it gives line numbers, be sure to tell us what lines in your code correspond to those line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> **Important Note:** You can only use [range based for-loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) in *C++11 or higher* if your compiler doesn't support **C++11** or higher, use [regular for-loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)...

Given your question, you **have** to use this structure (It is equivalent to the one in the question):

```
typedef struct
{
    std::string english;
    std::string pig_latin;
} Word;
```

This is a macro which is going to be used to check if the first letter is a *vowel* or a *consonant* (Hence, `!IS_VOWEL(some_char)`)...

```
#define IS_VOWEL(x) ((x) == 'A' || (x) == 'E' || (x) == 'I' || (x) == 'O' || (x) == 'U' || \
    (x) == 'a' || (x) == 'e' || (x) == 'i' || (x) == 'o' || (x) == 'u')
```

Another function which we need to acquire only the part of the word which has letters (not symbols and numbers):

```
std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> GetWord(std::string word)
{
    auto start = word.end();
    for (auto it = word.begin(); it != word.end(); ++it)
        if (tolower(*it) >= 'a' && tolower(*it) <= 'z' && start == word.end())
            start = it;
        else if (start != word.end() && !(tolower(*it) >= 'a' && tolower(*it) <= 'z'))
            return std::make_pair(std::distance(word.begin(), start), std::distance(word.begin(), it));
    return std::make_pair(start == word.end() ? 0 : std::distance(word.begin(), start), std::distance(word.begin(), word.end()));
}
```

And last but not least, the function to convert English to Pig-Latin (I know it is huge):

```
std::vector<Word> CreatePigLatinWordsFromEnglish(std::string english, bool sentence_case = true)
{
    // You can break it from here to use inside another function (viz., splitSentence)
    std::transform(english.begin(), english.end(), english.begin(), ::tolower);
    std::stringstream english_stream(english);
    std::vector<Word> words;
    std::string temporary;
    while (std::getline(english_stream, temporary, ' '))
        words.emplace_back(Word({ temporary, "" }));
    // Till here...
    // From here the conversion starts...
    for (auto &word : words)
    {
        auto const word_it = GetWord(word.english);
        if (!IS_VOWEL(word.english[word_it.first]) && !std::string(std::next(word.english.begin(), word_it.first),
            std::next(word.english.begin(), word_it.second)).empty())
        {
            word.pig_latin.append(std::string(word.english.begin(), std::next(word.english.begin(), word_it.first)));
            word.pig_latin.append(std::string(std::next(word.english.begin(), word_it.first + 1), std::next(word.english.begin(), word_it.second)));
            word.pig_latin.append(1, word.english[word_it.first]);
            word.pig_latin.append(std::string("ay"));
            word.pig_latin.append(std::next(word.english.begin(), word_it.second), word.english.end());
        }
        else
            word.pig_latin = std::string(word.english.begin(), std::next(word.english.begin(), word_it.second)) + "way"
                + std::string(std::next(word.english.begin(), word_it.second), word.english.end());
    }
    // Conversion ends here...
    // Changing the case from lower case to sentence case if needed...
    if (sentence_case)
    {
        words[0].english[0] = toupper(words[0].english[0]);
        words[0].pig_latin[0] = toupper(words[0].pig_latin[0]);
    }
    return words; // Returning the list of words we got...
}
```

> Well, an example to demonstrate this method:
>
> ```
> int main()
> {
>     auto const test = "An apple a day keeps the doctor away!";
>     for (auto word : CreatePigLatinWordsFromEnglish(test))
>         std::cout << word.pig_latin << " ";
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> > **Output:**
> >
> > *Anway appleway away ayday eepskay hetay octorday awayway!*
>
> Try it out and see whether it gives you the required result...

Kind regards,

Ruks.